# What is the coalesce() eqivalent?

Tags: soql, aggregate, count

Much like this post here: [SOQL: Avoid count with NULL results return 0 (zero) instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22712624/soql-avoid-count-with-null-results-return-0-zero-instead)

I have an instance where I am using aggregate functions like `COUNT()` and `MAX()` on a collection of Opportunities. These work just fine as long as my WHERE conditions don't filter out all opportunities, unfortunately if there are no rows to aggregate then my query returns 0 rows rather than returning 1 row as expected with the aggregate columns equal to '0'

The answer in the original response spoke of the `coalesce()` function. From what I can tell that is not a Salesforce method available to me. So is there an equivalent? How do I get my expected row returned with 0 values rather than null?

Here is an example of my SOQL:

```
SELECT AccountId, COUNT(Id) Invoices, AVG(Days_Past_Due__c) Average, Max(Days_Past_Due__c) Max
FROM Opportunity
WHERE AccountId IN :accountIds
AND IsDeleted = FALSE
AND {more conditions}
GROUP BY AccountId 
ORDER BY AccountId ASC NULLS FIRST
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide here

Comment: Did you try GROUP BY ROLLUP?

Comment: not sure how to do that

Comment: Never mind. I was thinking it might work. It doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [@sfdcfox's](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/79499/10834) answer I decided the only option to accomplish what I needed was to abandon SOQL aggregate columns and handling `AggregateResult` object. Instead because requirements of this task *(need AVG of all invoice opportunities, but MAX of only unpaid invoice opportunities)*, also in order to avoid some complicated version of multiple SOQL statements, my solution is to simply collect all Opportunities in relation to my `List<String>` of `AccountId`s and aggregate the data manually. For reference in case it helps anyone, here is a summation of my code:

```
public static void rollupAverageDaysPastDue (Set<String> accountIds){
    Set<Opportunity> all_invoices = new Set<Opportunity>([
        SELECT Id, AccountId, Days_Past_Due__c, Is_Paid__c
        FROM Opportunity
        WHERE AccountId IN :accountIds
        AND [is an invoice opportunity]
    ]);

    Map<Id,Integer> invoice_count = new Map<Id,Integer>();
    Map<Id,Decimal> invoice_sum = new Map<Id,Decimal>();
    Map<Id,Decimal> invoice_avg = new Map<Id,Decimal>();
    Map<Id,Decimal> invoice_max = new Map<Id,Decimal>();

    for(Opportunity opp : all_invoices) {
        /* Count every account opportunity */
        if( invoice_count.get(opp.AccountId) != NULL ){
            invoice_count.put(opp.AccountId, invoice_count.get(opp.AccountId)+1 ); // increment current count for this account ID
        } else {
            invoice_count.put(opp.AccountId,1);
        }

        /* Sum every account opportunity's Past Due Days */
        if( invoice_sum.get(opp.AccountId) != NULL ){
            /* add this opportunity to this account id summation */
            invoice_sum.put(opp.AccountId, invoice_sum.get(opp.AccountId)+opp.Days_Past_Due__c );
        } else {
            invoice_sum.put(opp.AccountId, opp.Days_Past_Due__c);
        }

        /* Sum every account opportunity's Past Due Days */
        if( opp.Is_Paid__c == FALSE ){
            if( invoice_max.get(opp.AccountId) != NULL ){
                if( invoice_max.get(opp.AccountId) <= opp.Days_Past_Due__c ){                         invoice_max.put(opp.AccountId, opp.Days_Past_Due__c);
                }
            } else {
                invoice_max.put(opp.AccountId, opp.Days_Past_Due__c);
            }
        }

    }

    /* Calculate average past due days for all invoices per account */
    for(Id aid : invoice_count.keySet()){
        Decimal average = invoice_sum.get(aid) / invoice_count.get(aid);
        invoice_avg.put(aid, average);
    }

    /* Iterate through account IDs to make a bulkified DML UPDATE */
}
```

Hope that can help someone stuck in similar situation. Good luck!

Comment: Is this written in Java?

Comment: @leeand00 APEX looks mostly like a superset of Java.

Answer (score 5):

No. There's no way to get the results you're looking for. SOQL is a very limited query language that isn't as robust as full SQL, although it handles relationships easier than SQL.

Comment: So is my only option to not use aggregate SOQL functions and instead return a collection of Opportunities that I manually iterate through and calculate count, average and max values?