# SOQL - max of a column on top 100 records - how to write?

Tags: soql

How can i rewrite proper SOQL query to get the below effect -

```
SELECT 
    coalesce(min(LastModifiedDate), 'NULL') minimum, coalesce(max(LastModifiedDate), 'NULL') minimum, 
    count(LastModifiedDate) total_count 
FROM  
    (SELECT 
        LastModifiedDate 
    FROM ACCOUNT 
    LIMIT 10 
    WHERE LastModifiedDate > xxxx and LastModifiedDate < xxxx
    )
```

or at least

```
SELECT 
    min(LastModifiedDate) minimum, max(LastModifiedDate) minimum, 
    count(LastModifiedDate) total_count 
FROM  
    (SELECT 
        LastModifiedDate 
    FROM ACCOUNT 
    LIMIT 10
    WHERE LastModifiedDate > xxxx and LastModifiedDate < xxxx
    )
```

Any help here will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You would need to use aggregateresult. See [Working With SOQL Aggregate functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm)

So it would be something like this:

```
AggregateResult groupedResults = [SELECT min(LastModifiedDate) min, 
                                         max(LastModifiedDate) max, 
                                         count(Name)
                                  FROM   Account
                                  WHERE  LastModifiedDate > xxxx && 
                                         LastModifiedDate < xxxx
                                  Group By Name
                                  LIMIT 10];
```

Also, fun fact you cannot do coalesce as described here: [What is the coalesce() eqivalent?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/79491/what-is-the-coalesce-eqivalent)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.. but this query fails with exception -
 MALFORMED_QUERY: Non-grouped query that uses overall aggregate functions cannot also use LIMIT and if i try GROUP BY with LastModifiedDate.. its throwing field 'LastModifiedDate' can not be grouped in a query call.  I am new to SOQL or salesforce.

Comment: Ahh, yes it seems you cannot do limit without group by. Your issues stems from the fact that you cannot group by a DateTime field. Does it matter what field you're grouping on? I suggest Name. I'll adjust my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately i need to group by on LastModifiedDate. All i am trying to do is trying to split records into batches each of 100 (n) records using LastModifiedDate (order by).. so that i can pull them in batches. Couldn't understand the best way using SOQL

Comment: Yeah it looks like you can't do the groupings. I'm stuck maybe someone else has a better idea.

Comment: Nowhere on your example code you grouped by LastModifiedDate. Can you let us know what you're trying to do (edit the Original Post)? I built a solution but it does not group by Date as you wish to do.

Comment: Group by on LastModifiedDate is w.r.t Dan's solution. How can we write an SOQL query for the following scenario - i want to split the records of Account object by LastUpdatedDate into batches of equal(~) number. And then aggregate it to find whats max and min LastModifiedDate.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

> You can't use a LIMIT clause in a query that uses an aggregate
>   function, but does not use a GROUP BY clause.

AND

> Some object fields have a field type that does not support grouping.
>   You can't include fields with these field types in a GROUP BY clause.
>   The Field object associated with DescribeSObjectResult has a groupable
>   field that defines whether you can include the field in a GROUP BY
>   clause.

There are basically 2 ways for you.

**One:**

You can do a simple SOQL order by Lastmodifieddate with a limit 100 and it will return you a list of records.

So the first record's lastmodifieddate will be `min(lastmodifieddate)` and that of the last one will be `max(lastmodifieddate)`. List size will be the count.

**Two:**

You can do this using 2 SOQL queries.

First fetch the first 100 records using a simple SOQL with a limit 100.

```
SELECT Id FROM Account LIMIT 100
```

save the result in a list, lets say - `accList`.

Now, do your Aggregate query filtering the records using the list.

```
SELECT MAX(LastModifiedDate),MIN(LastModifiedDate), count(Id) FROM Account where Id IN :accList
```

**Bonus point:**
There is a date function in SOQL - [DAY_ONLY](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_date_functions.htm)

This function returns the DAY part of the Datetime value. This function if used in a SOQL, the field can be grouped as well.

```
SELECT DAY_ONLY(LastModifiedDate), count(Id) FROM Account group by DAY_ONLY(LastModifiedDate) order by DAY_ONLY(LastModifiedDate) LIMIT 10
```

*Notice here:* The LIMIT 10 is not applied to the actual account list but on the aggregated rows.

So if you want to aggregate on the first 100 records, there is simply no way using single Aggregate Query.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes.. i wanted to know if there is any (hacky) way to aggregate on first or every hundred records using SOQL. Answers seems NO. I thought about the other logic which didn't seem right for me.

Comment: Approach two seems to do what you wrote in the question but using 2 queries.